# How to locate memory address in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone pls tell me how to pull the memory address of a variable? for example, how would I pull out the memory address of the following variables:

```
Dim x As Integer = 10
Dim y As Integer = 10
Dim s As String = "Test"
```

Comment: For curiosity. What would you like to do with the memory address of those variables?

Comment: check the immutability of value types. Saw a python video where the person declared x= 10; y=10 and z= 10. Surprisingly the memory address of all three variables were same. Similarly read that in VB.net strings once created cant be changed...when they are changed the old string is not changed rather a new string is created. Want to check all these things.

Comment: That might be pretty difficult (if not impossible) to accomplish just in VB.NET itself. Perhaps you could investigate the generated IL code and/or look into the internals of the [Roslyn compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). To be honest, I understand the curiosity behind the question, but I doubt the practical value of the answer very much.

Comment: It seems plausible to me that `x` and `y` will both be pointing to the same memory address when they are both initialized to literal value `10`. I assume the compiler can optimize the usage of literals and constants this way to save memory and/or improve performance. I guess all constants and literals are initialized upon application start and will be reused during its runtime. That would avoid subsequent memory allocations.

Comment: I don't really see this as an optimisation if they're not constans.

Comment: The compiler might very well place constants in memory and then load from that memory into variables.  However, knowing this isn't going to tell you anything about immutability unless you ask Windows for details on the protection of that memory.  The memory should be flagged as read-only so that you would get a crash if you were to try to write to it.

Comment: Back in the day, the Digital Fortran compiler did *not* put constants in read-only memory (this was fixed in the next version after the one I was working with at the time), and I had a fun debug session trying to figure out an issue that ultimately amounted to code that managed to redefine the constant 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Using only VB I don't think it's possible. But when you pass variables to .dll's by reference (ByRef), they get passed by address that you're looking for. A simple asm procedure can return it.

Actually there is a way:

1. start the program with a breakpoint set on the first statement.
2. In VS search box, look for *Disassembly*
3. Examine the addresses immediately after MOV instructions